# Defining the value of $n$ so this limit would equal $-∞$.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x \to -∞} \frac{\left(x^n+1\right)^{15}-\left(x^n-1\right)^{15}}{\left(x^n-3\right)^7+\left(x^n+2\right)^7} \ = -∞ $$
                                             -

( We need to find the values of $n$ so this limit would equal  $-∞$ )
I used some simplifications using the $a^n-b^n \\$ formulas and got $\lim_{x \to -∞} x^{2 n} \\$ )

Which can't be possible since $2n$ is an even number. 
i know for a fact that i can't put $n = 1/2$ because we haven't studied $a^k$ with $k$ part of the Q groups.

Any little hints would be so appreciated (just hints if i gave up i will make sure to tell you)

Comment: Hint: Note that nominator is $\sim 30x^{14n}$ by binomial theorem, and denominator is $\sim 2x^{7n}$, hence whole limit $= \lim_{x\to-\infty} 15x^{7n}$

Comment: Note that $n$ appears in the expression only through its influence on $x^n$.  So I'd start with the limit of $$ \frac{(z+1)^{15} - (z-1)^{15}}{(z-3)^7 + (z+2)^7}$$ as $z$ tends either to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ (because those are the only two viable choices).

Comment: @Ace This is wrong. See the comment by Jakobian.

Comment: thanks for the hint it is so appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use asymptotic *equivalents*:

By the binomial formula,
\begin{align}
(x^n+1)^{15}-(x^n-1)^{15}&=x^{15n}+15x^{14 n}+ o\bigl(x^{14n}\bigr)-\Bigl(x^{15n}-15x^{14n}+ o\bigl(x^{14n}\bigr)\Bigr)\\
&= 30x^{14n}++ o\bigl(x^{14n}\bigr),
\end{align}
so that $\;(x^n+1)^{15}-(x^n-1)^{15}\sim_\infty 30x^{14n}$.

Similarly,  $\;(x^n-3)^7+(x^n+2)^7\sim_\infty 2x^{7n}$,. Therefore
$$\frac{(x^n+1)^{15}-(x^n-1)^{15}}{(x^n-3)^7+(x^n+2t)^7}\sim_\infty \frac{30x^{14n}}{2x^{7n}}=15x^{7n}.$$

Comment: So this limit equals $-\infty$ whenever $n$ is an odd number?

Comment: Yes,   it's exactly that.